# Using Python to Connect/ Download file from SharePoint 2013

Tags: python, sharepoint-2013, xlsx

Seek your guidance, I am new @Python and in learning phase.

Problem Statement: I want to connect & Download the xlsx file from my office SharePoint 2013 site.

Steps so far:

```
import sharepy
s = sharepy.connect("https://office.XXX.com/sites/pkdyns")
r = s.getfile("https://office.XXX.com/sites/pkdyns/Shared%20Documents/YYYY.xlsx")
r = s.getfile("https://office.XXX.com/sites/pkdyns/Shared%20Documents/YYYY.xlsx", filename="/PYTHON/YYYY.xlsx")
```

After this I dont see the downloaded file, not sure if it ran or not, using Jupyter Notebook but it didnt throw up any error. Please suggest.

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 2):

sharepy library seems to only support sharepoint online.

[SharePy - Simple SharePoint Online authentication for Python](https://github.com/JonathanHolvey/sharepy)

Below is a sample about how to download file from sharepoint, you may take a reference( it uses another [library](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/README.md)):

```html
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.file import File

ctx = ClientContext.connect_with_credentials(url,UserCredential(username, password))
web = ctx.web
ctx.load(web)
ctx.execute_query()
print "Web title: {0}".format(web.properties['Title'])
 
path = "../../tests/data/SharePoint User Guide.docx"
response = File.open_binary(context, "Shared Documents/SharePoint User Guide.docx")
response.raise_for_status()
with open(path, "wb") as local_file:
     local_file.write(response.content)
```